# Assigned quantity from move lines in sale order line

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I want to show in sale.order.line for each product quantity that was assigned. It works when I have 1 sale order line, but if I have more it's the same qty for all product. but my code is bad because there is more than 1 move, so how can I do it right?

```py
reserved_qty = fields.Float(string='Reserved Qty', compute='_get_qtys') 


@api.depends('order_id.picking_id.move_lines.state')
    def _get_qtys(self):
        for line in self:
            domain = [('id', '=', line.order_id.picking_id.move_lines.id),
                      ('product_id', '=', line.product_id.id)
                      ]
            movez = self.env['stock.move'].search(domain)
            line.not_fulfiled_qty = line.product_uom_qty - line.qty_delivered
            if line.order_id.picking_id:
                for picking in line.order_id.picking_id:
                    for move in picking.move_lines:
                        if move.state == 'assigned':
                            line.reserved_qty = movez.product_uom_qty
```

UPDATE:

if found a solution it works fine, but still have a question can there be more than 1 procurement_ids? will there be singleton errors in some scenarios?

```py
@api.depends('order_id.picking_id.move_lines.state')
    def _get_qtys(self):
        for line in self:
            line.not_fulfiled_qty = line.product_uom_qty - line.qty_delivered
            if line.order_id.picking_id:
                for move in line.procurement_ids.move_ids:
                    if move.state == 'assigned':
                        line.reserved_qty = move.product_uom_qty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there are more procurements, just change your code to handle such situations:

```py
            for move in line.procurement_ids.mapped('move_ids'):
                if move.state == 'assigned':
```